# swrast driver fails to load with Nvidia drivers on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, nvidia

After switching from `nouveau` drivers to the Nvidia ones, my program crashes on start, saying that the swrast driver failed to load. The problem appears to be the drivers. I have the Nvidia drivers:

> lib32-nvidia-libgl 375.10-2
>   lib32-nvidia-utils 375.10-2
>   libvdpau 1.1.1-2
>   libxnvctrl 375.10-1
>   nvdock 1.02-5
>   nvidia 375.10-1
>   nvidia-libgl 375.10-2
>   nvidia-settings 375.10-1
>   nvidia-utils 375.10-2
>   opencl-nvidia 375.10-2

`LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo` gives some errors:

> name of display: :0.0
>   libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
>   libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
>   libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so
>   libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/pengowen/.drirc: No such file or directory.
>   libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/pengowen/.drirc: No such file or directory.
>   libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
>   libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>   X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
>     Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
>     Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
>     Serial number of failed request:  48
>     Current serial number in output stream:  47

Some info:

`uname -a`:

> Linux arch-pc 4.8.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 31 18:51:30 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`inxi -G`:

> Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GK110 [GeForce GTX 780]
>              Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 driver: nvidia Resolution: 1440x900@59.89hz
>              GLX Renderer: N/A GLX Version: N/A

My X log (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`) is here:
http://pastebin.com/ediKiaXe